# New to MINGW64 - command not found?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash, mingw-w64

I've been using MINGW64 for about 4 hours. So go easy on me. I'm having a problem where commands work when typed directly into the MINGW64 console, but fail when run from a simple .sh script.

```
Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ drewtemp="hihi"

Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ echo "${drewtemp}"
hihi

Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
﻿unity="hi"
echo "${unity}"

Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 2: ﻿unity=hi: command not found
```

Can anyone tell me why this simple sh script results in "command not found"?

Thanks!

Comment: try "fixing" your file with `dos2unix test.sh`. Then turn off Windows line endings in your editor to fix the problem permanently. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter really thought that was going to do it! However...Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ dos2unix test.sh
dos2unix: converting file test.sh to Unix format...

Administrator@EC2AMAZ-I2CVOT2 MINGW64 /c/BuildAgent
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 2: unity=hi: command not found

Comment: deleting the file and re-created it using vi fixed the issue. Thanks @shellter !!!